# Field calculation in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, vbscript, grouping

- i have a data which contain a code of area an value of area in shapefile, ex.:

area|value
1|33
1|43
1|31
2|12
2|43
3|66
3|76

the question is how to calculate total value per area with arcgis, i heve been tried with arcgis calculator and it doesnt work?
what i expect for result is

area|value|total
1|33|107
1|43|107
1|31|107
2|12|55
2|43|55
3|66|142
3|76|142

Answer (score 2):

this is a sumarize function.
You will need to right click on the area field and hit summarize.
Then add the value field and sum it.
After you complete that you can join that table back to the original data using the id field.

NOTE: it is advisable to not use the fid,OID field for your id. Just create a new field and calculate the value from fid into it.

Comment: using summarize doesnt group data by area, summarize calculate total of field

Comment: Use the Summary Statistics tool in ArcToolobox to get at the summarize and grouping (case field) functionality.

Comment: when he summarizes on "his" area field it will give a count of all the 1s, 2s, etc. adding the value and making it a sum, he will get 1,3,107. join that to the original data and he will get. 1,33, 107; etc.